# How to use multiple modifier keys in C#

Tags: c#, key, keyboard-shortcuts, keydown, modifier-key

I am using a keydown event to detect keys pressed and have several key combinations for various operations.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
{
    //Do work
}
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
{
    //Paste
}
```

For some reason the key combination in which I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is not working. I have re ordered them, and placed it at the top thinking it might be interference from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, and even removed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to see if it was causing a problem. It still does not work. I know it's probably something very simple, but can't quite grasp what it is. All of my 1 modifier + 1 key combination's work fine, as soon as I add a second modifier is when it no longer works.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Modifiers == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift))
{
    //Do work
}
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
{
    //Paste
}
```

Comment: i used the exact same code, holding down cntrl and shift, but the if never gets fired. Is there something i am possibly doing wrong in the real life execution?

Comment: @A.bakker, this is real life code that is verified works.  To debug your case, I'd suggest creating a `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C) {` condition and placing a breakpoint there.  Once the breakpoint is hit, inspect the value of `e.Modifiers` and adjust your code accordingly

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `e.Modifiers == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift)`?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> then use the bitwise OR (as `Keys` is a `Flags` enum)

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Modifiers == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift))
{
    //Do work (if Ctrl-Shift-C is pressed, but not if Alt is pressed as well)
}
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
{
    //Paste (if Ctrl is only modifier pressed)
}
```

This will fail if <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed as well

Answer (score 3):

```
      if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift | ModifierKeys.Control) > 0)
          Debugger.Launch();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to add an invisible menu item, assign the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut to it, and handle the event there.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> Undo and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> Redo operation and it worked.

```
  Private Sub Form_Main_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
      Case Keys.Add
        diagramView.ZoomIn()
      Case Keys.Subtract
        diagramView.ZoomOut()
      Case Keys.Z
        If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control + Keys.Shift Then
          diagram.UndoManager.Redo()
        ElseIf e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
          diagram.UndoManager.Undo()
        End If
    End Select
  End Sub
```

Comment: The question has a C# tag. This is not C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Should behave the way you want it to, and it's a little simpler.

```
 if (e.Control)
 {
    if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
       //Do work
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
       //Paste
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as no one else mentions them, i'm just going to leave the suggestion to use KeyEventArgs.KeyData:

```
if (e.KeyData == (Keys.C | Keys.Control | Keys.Shift)
{
  //do stuff
  //potentially use e.Handled = true
}
if (e.KeyData == (Keys.V | Keys.Control)
{
  //do other stuff
  //potentially use e.Handled = true
}
```

This should only act on specific key combinations, though the order of the modifiers don't seem to matter, the first one is always the last pressed key.

And e.Handled = true should stop it, though i don't know the specific mechanics behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach more suitable if you have more cases, and easier to read is:

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Action action = e.KeyData switch
    {
      (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.C) => DoWork,
      (Keys.Control | Keys.V) => Paste,
      _ => null
    };
    action?.Invoke();
}
private void DoWork() 
{ // do work }
private void Paste() 
{ // paste }
```