# Press key when CTRL is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KeyDown : recognizing multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265634/keydown-recognizing-multiple-keys)

Hi,
I would need to differ between two actions: key <kbd>A</kbd> is pressed and key <kbd>A</kbd> is pressed while <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is being pressed.
I am doing that:

```
..keyEventArgs k

if(k.Control)
{
  if(k.code==Keys.A)
   ..
}
else
{
  if(k.code==Keys.A)
    ..

}
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juding from the [Control property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.control.aspx), you are using winforms.

Yes, but consider writing it as follows:

```
if(k.KeyCode==Keys.A)
{
    if(k.Control)
    {
        ... Control+a
    }
    else
    {
        ... a
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay, 1 if lost. Does not really matter, both are perfectly understandable from reading the code.

Comment: @PoweRoy: Oh well, I felt stupid just answering 'Yes'. ;p

Answer (score 0):

Well, does it work?

Anyway, here are some examples you can use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

take a look to this post my friend ;)

[How to use multiple modifier keys in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434867/multiple-modifier-keys-in-c)

:)