# Keyboard shortcuts which needs 3 or more keys

Tags: c#

How could I make keyboard shortcuts which needs 3 or more keys to press?
Like Ctrl+Alt+S?

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
{
        SAVEc_FORCE();
}
```

but it don't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt` is always false because they are `key == a && key == b`. Read this post to learn how to use multiple ModifierKeys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434867/how-to-use-multiple-modifier-keys-in-c-sharp

Comment: [ModifierKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a [Key bitmask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx). It should be used as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to combine the keys:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S && (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control | Keys.Alt))
```

`Keys` are flags - a single value is made up of all the individual enum values (any you want). So when you press both `Control` and `Alt` at the same time, that corresponds to a value of `Keys.Control | Keys.Alt`. Of course, this means that neither `Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control` nor `Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt` return `true` - even though `ModifierKeys` *contains* both of those, it's not *equal* to either of those.

As an extension, if you want to match `Keys.Control` regardless of the status of the remaining modifier keys, you can do this:

```
(Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control
```

or

```
Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control)
```

Comment: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S && (Control.ModifierKeys == (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt)))` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to code it this way:

`if(e.KeyCode == Keys.S && e.Modifiers == (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt))`