# How to get keypress event in console for different keys

Tags: c#, keypress

I tried googling this but I can't find an answer to this (hope it isn't just my bad searching skills). But what I currently have is this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (xa == true)
        {

                switch (switchNum)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Text");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Stuff");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("More Stuff");
                        break;
                }       

        }
```

And what I want to know is how to change the switchNum when I press a key. Hopefully 3 different keys for each case.

EDIT: Clarification

So currently it will type out of the console like this:

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
```

And I want it to change to something else when I press a key e.g. "w"

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
//Press w here
Stuff
Stuff
Stuff
Stuff
//Pressing another key e.g. q
More Stuff
More Stuff
More Stuff
...
```

So what I don't know is how to receive different keys, and to keep the loop going (therefore, readkey() might not work).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use readkey instead??

Comment: u mean three different keyboard key for each case?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Is this what you are after? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would you please provide the type declarations for xa and switchNum?

Comment: the xa and switchNum are just ints im using to make the loop and switch work, i want to change switchNum so I can choose between the 3 cases.

Comment: @JaneS I don't know how to read specific keys, while not stopping the loop using readkey. Basically, I want the console to constantly type out one of the cases, and when I press a key, I can change to another case, so the console changes what it writes.

Comment: @Rerxx This may have what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849876/c-sharp-simultanous-console-input-and-output

Comment: Or this :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Console.ReadKey() to see when a key is press, and as that function is a blocking function you can use Console.KeyAvailable to only call it when you know the user is pressing something.
You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://dutton.me.uk/2009/02/24/non-blocking-keyboard-input-in-c/).

Your code can be changed to:

```
//console input is read as a char, can be used in place of or converted to old switchNum you used
char input = 'a';//define default so the switch case can use it

while (xa == true)
{
    //If key is pressed read what it is.
    //Use a while loop to clear extra key presses that may have queued up and only keep the last read
    while (Console.KeyAvailable) input = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;

    //the key read has been converted to a char matching that key
    switch (input)
    {
        case 'a':
            Console.WriteLine("Text");
            break;
        case 's':
            Console.WriteLine("Stuff");
            break;
        case 'd':
            Console.WriteLine("More Stuff");
            break;
    }
}
```

.

EDIT:  As Jane commented, the loop you're using has no limiter, it will cycle as fast as the CPU running it can go.  You should definitely include `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()` in the loop to take a rest between each cycle, or wait for a key before printing by converting the `while (Console.KeyAvailable) key = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar` to just `key = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar`

Comment: I was just about to post an answer but this covers what I was going to respond with.  The only thing I might have added to your sample is a small wait sequence after the `switch` statement so the poor console text isn't running at a million miles a minute :)

Comment: indeed, add 'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)' to slow the loop to a max 20 loops/sec, or change 50 to the number of ms you want to wait.

Comment: Thanks!, this works, but just to make sure, when you wrote 'key' did you mean input?

Comment: @JaneS I already had a 1 second delay between the loops, but removed it for clarity, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Rerxx Yeah sorry, the variable 'key' should have 'input' there instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on solution based on timing-out ReadKey() after every short-intervals  [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline/57655#57655)
with Console.Write("\b"); to backspace on entered Key.

However **@Skean 's** solution is great. Building on his answer: -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        bool xa = true;
        int switchNum = 48; // ASCII for '0' Key
        int switchNumBkup = switchNum; // to restore switchNum on ivalid key
        while (xa == true)
        {    
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                switchNumBkup = switchNum; // to restore switchNum on ivalid key
                switchNum = key.KeyChar; // Get the ASCII of keyPressed
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Esc Key was pressed. Exiting now....");
                    Console.ReadKey(); // TO Pause before exiting
                    break;
                }
            }
            switch (switchNum)
            {

                    case 48: //ASCII for 0
                        Console.WriteLine("Text");
                        break;
                    case 49: //ASCII for 1
                        Console.WriteLine("Stuff");
                        break;
                    case 50: //ASCII for 2
                        Console.WriteLine("More Stuff");
                        break;
                    default :
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Key. Press Esc to exit.");
                        switchNum = switchNumBkup;
                        break;
            }                
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200) ;                
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting ");
    }
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using int, then converting it to ASCII, rather than just using char, as Skean did? Or is it just because in my question I used int? Thanks though, for the improved answer with an reset to a valid key.

Comment: @Skean Your solution is great. If user enters say 'f' key the app will stop emitting text to console until 'a', 's', or 'd' is keyed-in.

Comment: @Rerxx I used int just because you mentioned.